# Where to insert .js code using the webform module for google tracking a submit button?

Tags: webforms, forms

I am trying to insert a google tracker to a form submit button/form using the webform module (drupal 7).  Here is my code:

`Drupal.behaviors.basicWorks = function(context) {
  // Track submission events.
  $('#webform-client-form-198', context).submit(function() {
    ga('send', {'hitType': 'event', 'eventCategory': 'PDTestlinktoDrupal', 'eventAction': 'clickAction', 'eventLabel': 'PDConversionTest' });
  });

};`

My question is:

Where do I place this code?  Inside the webform.js inside the /js folder?  Or do I create my own file inside the /js folder and upload?

Been working on this issue for a few days now and I could really use some insight.

Comment: Add the above code to a JS file in your module

Comment: Please don't use signatures in your questions. Your questions are linked to your account; if you want to add anything about you, your profile is the place where to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the script.js file in to your theme folder
2. Copy paste the above code into it
3. Specify the script.js path in the .info file of the theme as
   `scripts[] = script.js`

Comment: I tried this method and I am still not getting any hits in google.  Thank you for your suggestion.  I will keep troubleshooting.

Comment: I guess it will reflect in your GA statistics after 24 hrs fro the code integration

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 option:
1- using #attached to the $form element. use `hook_form_alter`

```
function YourMODULE_form_webform_client_form_1_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'YourMODULE') . '/js/your_script.js',
  );
}
```

2- add it in your custom module with [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) function, Also it will be much better if you just load the js on only that page (web form page) so you will avoid loading it on every page.

Comment: ... and if 2- then best via `hook_page_build()`

Comment: The challenge is that the form is on every single page except for a couple.  So I would like to avoid having to place the code on every page.

I will give this a shot although I am not familiar with using hooks.  (beginner)